# Screen rotation causes trouble with secuential calls to SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, rotation, restore

If you are an experienced Android programmer, you probably know Screen orientation causes the app to be saved and restored via the onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState.

you will probably also know that objects are not easy to restore via those features, for example, if i create a database connection as follows:

```
SQLiteDatabase mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(dbn.trim().toLowerCase(), 0, null);
```

And then i execute a query for loading a record as follows:

```
Cursor rs = mydb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE where id>0", null);
```

Afterwards i can read next matching record just by using:

```
rs.moveToNext();
```

Now here comes the semi-bad news... if during a secuential call to SQLite as i just explained, the user tilts the device, everything is deleted and then restored, except objects like the Cursor containing the result set. So, even the SQLite connection gets reset!

Now, i know one can lock screen orientation during such tasks, whether we make it programmatically or via the Android Manifest. So, no problem.

Now, for the bad news... When you invoke an Intent using startActivityForResult(), you cannot control the screen orientation of the invoked feature! So, the host application is rotated even if you specifically configured the app to lock orientation. And there doesn't seem to be an intuitive fix for this.

This causes a series of issues from null pointers to all sorts of crashes.

I dont have the control over when the user will finish the secuential SQLite call, or when the user will invoke startActivityForResult(), Is there a way to avoid all this? I was thinking if there would just be a way to lock the screen rotation of the whole device programmatically....

Comment: Can you not save the position then use `Cursor.moveToPosition(index)` when you detect a screen rotation?

Comment: Since the index is an Integer, yes, I can save the position of the cursor. But i cannot save the cursor itself, because it is not a serializable Object. Same goes for the database connection itself. The database I can simply re-open, but for the cursor, i would need to reissue the query and that might be resource intensive.

Comment: Ah right, I though you were reopening the database. Then why not use a [ContentQueryMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentQueryMap.html)? It can save a Cursor.

Comment: The easiest way is to turn off the activity restart behavior in the manifest by setting your configChanges variable on the activity(s) in question.  It was braindead behavior by Google from the start.

Comment: Hey Gabe, thanks for the suggestion, I tried it like 50 minutes ago but the app resources would not compile, probably I am using an usupported API version. I will try again with API 22.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the configuration changes so that the app doesn't shut down during screen rotations.  In your manifest  section, put

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
```

This will call Activity.onConfigurationChanged() in your app when the orientation or screen size changes instead of restarting it.

In my app, all I do is this (which isn't technically needed):

```
@Override public boolean onConfigurationChanged (Configuration newConfig)
{
  super.onConfigurationChanged (newConfig);
}
```

I didn't need to add any code to refresh the views - they were automatically invalidated and regenerated.

For more details, see
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: Outstanding. It works. I still think the restarting of the app this way is a dumb behaviour. The OS should be able to do it automatically instead of having to do it this ugly way. Thanks Peri. :)